# convert variables into dictonaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have something like this where trade_date, effective_date and termination_date are date values:

```
tradedates = dict(((k, k.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) 
  for k in (trade_date,effective_date,termination_date)))
```

I get this:

```
{datetime.date(2005, 7, 25): '2005-07-25',
 datetime.datetime(2005, 7, 27, 11, 26, 38): '2005-07-27',
 datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 26, 11, 26, 38): '2010-07-26'}
```

What I would like is:

```
{'trade_date':'2005-07-25','effective_date':'2005-07-27','termination_date':'2010-07-26'}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Yes falsetru that's correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`vars`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

```
>>> import datetime
>>>
>>> trade_date = datetime.date(2005, 7, 25)
>>> effective_date = datetime.datetime(2005, 7, 27, 11, 26, 38)
>>> termination_date = datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 26, 11, 26, 38)
>>>
>>> d = vars() # You can access the variable as d['name']
>>> tradedates = {
...     name: d[name].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
...     for name in ('trade_date', 'effective_date', 'termination_date')
... }
>>> tradedates
{'effective_date': '2005-07-27', 'termination_date': '2010-07-26', 'trade_date': '2005-07-25'}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks your answer is correct but can you explain what is d = vars()

Comment: I added a comment to the code. Or follow the link in the answer.

Comment: Hi what is d = vars() though i never seen this syntax ever

Comment: @jhon.smith falsetru has a link to the documentation for you - that'll be worth reading first :)

Comment: @jhon.smith, syntax? It's a just a assignment statement.

Comment: @jhon.smith, What `vars()` returns is a dictionary mapping variable names to values of the variables. (when called without argument)

Answer (score 4):

For something that size, I'd create the `dict` directly:

```
result = {
    'trade_date': format(trade_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
    'effective_date': format(effective_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
    # etc....
}
```

Comment: Hi Very elegant solution clear for a novice like me to understand

Comment: @jhon.smith nope - that's fine. I would personally pick falsetru's as well. Take the time to understand why/how the solution works and you'll be fine...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question right. But let me explain what I understood and my answer for that:

You know the variable names: trade_date,effective_date,termination_date 
And they have data in them

You could easily do:

```
tradedates = dict()
for k in ('trade_date','effective_date','termination_date'):
    tradedates[k] = eval(k).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')      // eval will evaluate them as a variable name not as a string.
```

This will give you a final dict something like:

```
{
  'trade_date': <date_string_according_to_the_format_above>
  'effective_date': <date_string_according_to_the_format_above>
  'termination_date': <date_string_according_to_the_format_above>
}
```

Comment: Although this'll work using `eval` here is not recommended - `vars/globals` as shown by @falsetru would be the preferred method to pull from the namespace instead...

Comment: Unfortunately - the change you've made `eval(k.strftime(...))` will eval the formatted date, you want to apply the formatting to the resultant object otherwise you'll end up doing subtraction on the date element - eg - today will be: `eval('2014-02-21')` which gives `1991` :)

Comment: @JonClements Right. Sorry missed the misplaced brackets. Fixed it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: There are so many better ways to do this than with `eval()` - and eval is _dangerous_ if misused.